# Hash-only href location in Ember

Tags: javascript, html, dom, ember.js, href

In an Ember app I'm building, I have a hash-only link like so: `<a href="#foo">Foo</a>`, on a page that *isn't* the root (i.e. `localhost/bar`). If I inspect the element in the console, the `href` property is `localhost#foo`, instead of `localhost/bar#foo` like it is on other sites. `window.location.href` return `localhost/bar`, so the browser definitely knows where it is.

What could be causing this discrepancy?[image]

Comment: I'm afraid history api and classical hashes don't play nicely together.

Comment: Got a `base` element in there …?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if hash links can work with client side routing right outside the box.

I think you could check out `ember-href-to` which should always generate correct url for you.

Something like

`<a href={{concat (href-to "some-route") "#myhash"}}>`

(concat helper is not a default Ember helper)

That should provide correct url, but making the anchor actually work, that's another problem. Switching to query-params would be much easier.

EDIT:

Apparently there's this addon as well: https://github.com/mike-north/ember-anchor